# How to add variables based on external data to a tabular{tables} summary table

Tags: r, latex, multiple-columns, knitr, tabular

Is it possible to add rows (or columns) to a summary table based on an external object with `tabular()` ?

This works:

```
tabular( (Sepal.Width+Petal.Width) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Species)*(mean + sd), data=iris )
```

This does not:

```
var <- names(iris)[c(2,4)]
tabular( (var) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Species)*(mean + sd), data=iris )
```

Is there a simple way to choose variables using another object, or do I really have to call them  by their name?

Disclaimer: I'm new to both latex and the package `{tables}`, so please forgive my naivety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
tabular( parse(text = paste(var, collapse = "+")) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Species)*(mean + sd), data=iris )
```

then you will get

```
                 Species                                    
                 setosa       versicolor      virginica     
             n   mean    sd   mean       sd   mean      sd  
 Sepal.Width 150 3.43    0.38 2.77       0.31 2.97      0.32
 Petal.Width 150 0.25    0.11 1.33       0.20 2.03      0.27
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick! My first time ever to use parse(). 
Now I need to learn how to add my chosen rownames to the table - attributes(obj)$rowLables <- rownames.latexcoded works, but I can't convert to latex afterwards (because I insert. Got trouble inserting latex code (like P$_2$O$_5 _a_v$).

Comment: @WilliamBligh, before getting excited about `parse` you should consider `fortune(106)` (and possibly `fortune(181)`).  Often there are better alternatives to using `parse`.

Comment: @GregSnow, thanks for the warning. However, I spent some time thinking, and as you said, it quite probably is overkill to create a full character string for each table.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the formula from a character string, then pass that to the `tabular` function:

```
tmp <- as.formula( paste( paste(var, collapse = "+"), "~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Species)*(mean + sd)") )
tabular(tmp, data=iris)
```

If you want to avoid `paste` and any type of character representation, then here is another option that works (but is probably overkill for most simple tables):

```
library(tables)
var <- names(iris)[c(2,3,4)]
form <- (var) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Species)*(mean + sd)
tmpfun <- function(a,b) {
    if( is.character(a) ) {
        substitute( `+`(aa,bb), list(aa=as.name(a),bb=as.name(b)) )
    } else {
        substitute( `+`(aa,bb), list(aa=a, bb=as.name(b)) )
    }
}
form[[2]] <- Reduce(tmpfun, var)

tabular( form, data=iris )
```